# JS file running ok when executing alone but when running with Ionic gives 'require is not defined' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework

I have an issue. I want to call a function from a js file in my Ionic project. When running the js file alone, the code works exactly as expected, but when im declaring the function from a typescript file, im getting the error : 'require is not defined'.
Any ideas?

**Thank you**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client on Node.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: I am looking at the top answer, which says to use the <script> tag, can you help me a bit with that?